# C - how to fix to work printf in this code?

Tags: c

I'm C begginer.I'm making typing practice program for practice.
In line 42,it doesn't work printf.I want print rand_n.
I think it maybe array problem but i can't fix this code.
can you help me?
Thanks.Have a good day!

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <time.h>
3 #include <string.h>
4 #include "getch.h"
5
6 int main()
7 {
8     char se[5][6][100]={{"AND THEN THERE WERE NONE", ....
27     .....    ," Young Lord L had surrendered to Cupid at last"}};
28
29
30     char mysent;
31     int accu=0,pro=0;
32     int rand_n;
33     double typing=0.0;
34     srand(time(NULL));
35     rand_n=rand()%1000;
36     time_t start=0,end=0;
37     typing = accu*60.00/(end-start);
38
39
40     printf(">>  typing practice <<\n");
41     printf("accuracy : %d%%  typing_pre_sec : %d\n",accu,typing);
42     printf("%s\n",se[rand_n]);
```

Comment: `rand_n` has a range of 0..999, but your array `se` has 3 dimensions, none of which is that large - what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: `se[rand_n]` --> `se[(0..4)][(0..5)]`

Comment: i want call sentene randomly in se.

Comment: Thanks!Now,i can try other way.

Answer (score 1):

`se` is a 3D array of character. Or a 2D array of strings. You are indexing it only once, so `se[rand_n]` is actually an array of strings. You probably don't want it to be a 3D array in the first place. Remove `[5]` from the declaration.

Also, `rand_n` can be anywhere between 0 and 999. You probably want to do `rand() % 5` or something.